# Responsive grid design with middle column dropping

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am building a simple grid with three columns. In case of smaller screens (or large data) I want the **middle column** to move to next row, instead of the usual behaviour.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h2>left</h2>
            Loremipsumdolorsitamet, consecteturadipiscingelit,
            seddoeiusmodtemporincididunt utlaboreetdoloremagnaaliqua.
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <h2>middle</h2>
            Loremipsumdolorsitamet, consecteturadipiscingelit,
            seddoeiusmodtemporincididunt utlaboreetdoloremagnaaliqua.
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <h2>right</h2>
            Loremipsumdolorsitamet, consecteturadipiscingelit,
            seddoeiusmodtemporincididunt utlaboreetdoloremagnaaliqua.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In other words, on big screens it looks like this:

```
|| left | middle | right ||
```

but if all three columns don't fit next to each other I want this:

```
|| left | right ||
||    middle   ||
```

instead of this:

```
|| left | middle ||
||    right      ||
```

I thought i could do it by writing them in "wrong" order and adding .order-first and .order-last but it made no difference.

I'm using the bootstrap version 4.1.3

(Edit)
As a bonus, for very small screens (or very large data) I want them to go back to original order:

```
|| left   ||
|| middle ||
|| right  ||
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [ordering classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#reordering) to re-order on smaller screen widths...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h2>left</h2> 
        </div>
        <div class="col order-last order-lg-0">
            <h2>middle</h2> 
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <h2>right</h2> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/MymyDd01KK

To answer the 2nd issue in the *edited* question... Again, you'd use the ordering classes to "reset" the order on the smallest xs breakpoint with `order-0`. `order-*-0` will use the columns' natural order, which in the case of "middle" is 2nd.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
            <h2>left</h2> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm order-0 order-sm-last order-lg-0">
            <h2>middle</h2> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            <h2>right</h2> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/wZCvHbtW4U

Comment: nice, is it possible to make them revert to original order when they all wrap on very small screens?

Comment: like i wrote in the question is did try order-last but on it's own it did not work, i don't understand order-lg-0

Comment: @MiloBem I updated the answer, but the original question was already answered.